# sql inner join view table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I need to join 2 tables through a "view" to obtain for each person(IdData), how many accounts he has and how many deposits have been made. The columns that I want to obtain are: `IdData`, `NUmberOfAccounts`, `NumberOfDeposits`

> Accounts:

- AccountNUmber
- DateAccount
- Value
- IdData

> Deposits:

- DepositNumber
- DateDeposit
- ValueDeposit
- AccountNumber(foreign key)

I don't know exactly how to join this information. Separately looks like this. I need to join them somehow.

```
select count(Accounts.AccountNUmber) as NUmberOfAccounts,IdData
from Accounts
group by IdData

select count(Deposits.AccountNUmber) as NumberOfDeposits,IdData
from Deposits inner join Accounts on Deposits.AccountNUmber=Accounts.AccountNUmber
group by IdData
```

Comment: Please set up an SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query:

select a.idData, 
count(a.accountNumber) as NumberOfAccounts,
(select count(depositNumber) from deposits
 where accountNumber = a.idData) as NumberOfDeposits
from accounts a
group by idData

this is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36ffd/7)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT a.idData,
count(a.AccountNumber) AS NumberOfAccounts,
(
     SELECT count(depositNumber) FROM deposits as b 
     WHERE b.accountNumber = a.accountNumber
) 
AS NumberOfDeposits
FROM accounts a
GROUP BY iddata;
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc87a/11)

Comment: it's not working, there are some errors ->                              Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure cerinta5, Line 3
Column 'deposits.accountnumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.